# Replacing file using vbscripting from the exe file

Tags: vbscript

I want to replace a file using vbscripting and this code works perfectly .

```
strFileToCopy = "C:\revisions.txt"
strFolder = "C:\Program Files (x86)\"

On Error Resume Next


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
   objFSO.CopyFile strFileToCopy, strFolder, TRUE ' true for overwrite  
Else
  Wscript.Echo "Target Folder does not exist."
End If
```

Here "replace.vbs" is the vbscript and "revisions.txt" is the file to be replaced .
But I want to convert  this "replace.vbs" into  "replace.exe" file which includes the "revisions.txt" .

to replace "revisions.txt" two files are needed .

1. "replace.vbs"
2. revisions.txt

but I want to include "revisions.txt" with  "replace.exe" so that the file   replacing can be done with just one standalone .exe file .

How to do this ? pls help.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Your question is not clear ? can you edit your post and explain more your issue ? what did you mean by "replace.vbs to replace.exe"  did you mean convert it into .exe file ? or something else ?

Comment: specific location . I can do this with the code in my previous question and I named it "replace.vbs" and I want to convert into  .exe file . And my issue is to replace a file I need to things , one is a vbscript code and another one is the file itself . But I want to make one standalone .exe file by which the file will be included in .exe file .

Comment: is this "exe" thing mandatory? I'm asking because you still can embed a text file into a VBScript file, so in the end you have one script file instead one exe file. isn't it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a self-extracting executable that runs a file using 7zip.

You need to download some additional files, even if you already have it installed, called 7z920_extra.7z. You can download them [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/9.20/7z920_extra.7z) or find them on their [sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/9.20/).

If you have that package you can create self extracting archives, as described [here in more detail](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/sfx.htm).

For your specific problem you would create a utf8 textfile config.txt with the following content:

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
ExecuteFile="replace.vbs"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

and save it in the same folder as you extracted the extra files. Then you just make a normal 7zip archive of replace.vbs and revisions.txt, name it replace.7z, and save it within the same folder.
Now open a cmd window, navigate to that folder and execute the command:

```
copy /b 7zS.sfx + config.txt + replace.7z replace.exe
```

to get your executable. As you can see on the [page I linked earlier](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/sfx.htm), there are also additional things you can do with those exes such as prompts.

A final thing to note: As long as you just replace a txt file you can also leave out this whole exe thing and just write the txt file from within the vbs. The [OpenTextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method would allow for this, making the whole thing one file (vbs not exe though) again. This will not really work with binary files however.